# React Native: useState not updating properly

Tags: react-native, use-state

I am new to react-native and I am kinda stuck. The issue is simple I try to update my the state of my product's quantity, so the total can be calculated, but before the product quantity gets updated my total is calculated on previous product's quantity.

```js
    // initially I set my products from a Global List known as cart
    const [products, setProducts] = useState(Global.cart);

    const updateQuantity = (item, qty) => {
      const product_index = products.findIndex(
        (product) =>
          product.id === item.id &&
          product.size === item.size &&
          product.color === item.color
      );
      const current_product = products[product_index];
      if (current_product.quantity + qty != 0) {
        if (current_product.quantity + qty <= 5) {
          const new_product = {
            ...products[product_index],
            quantity: current_product.quantity + qty,
          };
          const new_products = [...products];
          console.log("new_product--", new_products);
          new_products.splice(product_index, 1, new_product);
          console.log("new_product", new_products);
          setProducts(new_products);
          Global.cart = new_products;
          // updating the total as quantity updates of a single product
          calculateTotal();
        } else {
          alert("Can not add more quantity.");
        }
      } else if (current_product.quantity + qty == 0) {
        // removing the item from cart
        showRemoveAlert(item);
      }
    };

    const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
      const calculateTotal = () => {
      var temp_total = 0;
      for (let product of products) {
        temp_total = temp_total + product.quantity * product.price;
      }
      setTotal(temp_total);
    };

    // calculating the total first time as the screen loads
    useEffect(() => {
      calculateTotal();
    }, []);
```

I am updating the products before the calculateTotal is called so I should get the updated total but the issue is calculateTotal gets executed on the previous state of the products. Why the state of the products is not being updated first? What am I doing wrong?

I am not adding the whole design of the screen and single item that is rendered on screen. If still required do let me know I'll add accordingly.

Comment: you are calling calculateTotal inside useEffect that's why it's executing first

Comment: I did it like that, because I need to calculate the total at first render and when the quantity of a single product is increased the total is calculated again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When updateQuantity exicutes after updating the state, when you call calculateTotal function that time the function will have the previous state only, so instead of creating a state for total you can use useMemo hook to get the total whenever products updates.

Here's is the example:

```
export default function App() {
  const [products, setProducts] = React.useState([{price: 2, quantity: 1}])

  
  // Chage this internal for loop as required
  const {total} = React.useMemo(() => {
    let total = 0;
    products.forEach(({price, quantity}) => {
      total += price * quantity
    
    })
      return {total}
  }, [products])

  const increase= () => {
    setProducts([{price: 2, quantity: 2}])
    calculateTotal()
  }

  const calculateTotal =() => {
    console.log(products)
  }

    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text onPress={increase} style={styles.paragraph}>
       Price: {total || 0}
      </Text>
     
    </View>
  );
}
```

snack link: https://snack.expo.io/@ashwith00/ranting-nachos

Comment: Thanks mate works like a charm :), need to learn more about using hooks

Comment: Hi there. Please don't misspell posts deliberately here, either for stylistic or mobile-phone reasons - Stack Overflow is a professional resource and should be treated as such.